# after applying fetch next in query application not showing data

Tags: sql-server

I have performance issue in my db which is in sql server 2008. So, i have decided to move on sql server 2012.

I have changed my store procedure for paging using **OFFSET, FETCH NEXT** functionality.

Now, In sql server management studio it is working fine But, in application it is not returning any values(i am using data adapter to fill data set). If i change old paging than it is working again. I don't know why it happens? anybody can tell me why this happen????

Answer (score 0):

Run your app with SQLProfile turned on.  Verify that the SQL your app is sending to the SQLServer is indeed what you expect.  If it is, copy that TSQL from SQLProfiler and run it SSMS and see if it's yielding the results you expect.